# Debug view (dbgView) doesn't capture OutputDebugString

Tags: c, debugging, winapi, debugview

I have this very simple program (a test one), to test the function OutputDebugString.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>

int main()
{
    OutputDebugStringA("Hello string");
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it and open dbgView, it won't show up there.
I ran both programs as administrator. I have no clue on what the problem might be.
Help

Comment: Have you tried not to run dbgview as administrator?

Comment: yeah, I tried running it as administrator only after it didn't work as not administrator.

Comment: It works for me if I run it not as admin. Always had various problems with DbgView (including locked .sys driver etc.) that's why I wrote an alternate version : https://github.com/smourier/TraceSpy that doesn't everything it does but works for most cases.

Comment: Are you running your app inside a debugger? DbgView can't capture messages when the app is inside a debugger, the debugger will get the messages instead

Comment: *However, when I run it and open dbgView, it won't show up there.* Besides, [DebugView will immediately capture debug output after starting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview#installation-and-use). @nortain32